# YII. Миграция и две базы данных

Tags: миграция, php, yii

В проекте используется две бд.
При написании и выполнении миграции возникает исключение:

```
exception 'CDbException' with message
'CDbConnection.connectionString cannot
be empty.
```

В отладчике

```
\#3
/var/www/dev/framework/cli/commands/MigrateCommand.php(442):
CModule->getComponent('db')
```

Т.е. миграция обращается к компоненту **'db'**, однако в конфиге для консольных приложений такого компанента нет.

```
return array(
    'components' => array(
        'site_db' => array(
            'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=site',
            'class' => 'CDbConnection',
            'emulatePrepare' => true,
            'username' => '###',
            'password' => '###',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ),
        'dev01_db' => array(
            'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dev_01',
            'class' => 'CDbConnection',
            'emulatePrepare' => true,
            'username' => '###',
            'password' => '###',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ),
        'authManager' => array(
            'class' => 'CDbAuthManager',
            'connectionID' => 'site_db',
        ),
    )
);
```

Вопрос: где я ошибся в конфиге?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Миграциям надо задавать компонент для соединения, в противном случае берется стандартный db (оно ж само не определит куда вы хотите данные скидывать). [Здесь](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/ru/database.migration#sec-9) показано, как настроить команду миграций.